# Object-defined VBA error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, scope, userform

I have an Excel worksheet with a button on it. When pressed, it runs:

```
Sub Open_Constraints()
    UserForm7.Show
End Sub
```

UserForm7 has a button on it as well. When clicked it runs code stored under "UserForm7" which says:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm7.Hide
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

From there, UserForm1 has a ton of option boxes and check boxes on it with if statements as seen below. However, whenever the value is "true" for either a check box or option box, it returns an object or application defined error. Here is a small snippet of the code that could trigger it:

```
If UserForm1.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Sheets(ConstraintsSheet).Cells(ProfessorRow, 3).Value = "Y"
ElseIf UserForm1.OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    Sheets(ConstraintsSheet).Cells(ProfessorRow, 3).Value = "N"
End If
```

Any thoughts? Every single OptionBox and CheckBox triggers it, and ConstraintsSheet and ProfessorRow are definitely defined, as are the UserForm and OptionButton names. I think a scope issue might be  going on but not sure how to solve/reference things better.

Comment: What are `ConstraintsSheet` and `ProfessorRow` defined as and what are there values when executed?

Comment: Which line gives you the error? Try stepping through the code

Comment: Please add `MsgBox "ConstraintsSheet is " & ConstraintsSheet & " and ProfessorRow is " & ProfessorRow` just before the `If` block and tell us what you see.

Comment: Moreover, please tell us if you get the error on the line `If UserForm1.OptionButton1.Value = True Then` or on the line `Sheets(ConstraintsSheet).Cells(ProfessorRow, 3).Value = "Y"`, because the answer might be much different depending on this.

Comment: Gareth - this is the definition of them in the code for when the button in UserForm1 is clicked
    Dim ProfessorRow As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim ConstraintsSheet As String
Matteo - "ConstraintsSheet is Constraints and ProfessorRow is 0
Error is on the Sheets(ConstraintsSheet).Cells(ProfessorRow, 12).Value = "p"

Comment: @DarrenCole provide more code in your question by appending `constraintsSheet` and `ProfessorRow` definition part (what Gareth asked in first comment above).

Comment: @DarrenCole: here we go. If the MsgBox says that ProfessorRow is 0, and if you try to execute this line of code: `Cells(0,1) = 2`, you will get exactly the error you report in your question. I update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you have provided, I think the error lies either on `ConstraintsSheet` or on `ProfessorRow`. If you say:

"*ConstraintsSheet and ProfessorRow are definitely defined, as are the UserForm and OptionButton names*", it means that what you're trying to do is this:

```
Sheets(UserForm1.Name).Cells(UserForm1.OptionButton1.Name, 3) = "Y"
```

So, a **possible** problem might be that there's not a sheet in your workbook which is called as the **name** of the userform. 
On the other hand, it is **sure** that this will cause an error:

```
Cells(UserForm1.OptionButton1.Name,3)
```

This is because the parameter for the `Cells(i,j)` must be an integer, while the name of the option button is **definitely not** a number (you would get invalid name error if you try to name the option button with a number). Probably, if your option buttons captions are numbers, you might probably want to write

```
Cells(UserForm1.OptionButton1.Caption,3)
```

Anyway, I must say that I'm not able to reproduce your same error like this (because these kind of errors should normally be a "index list out of range" type), but I'm just sticking to your sentence *"and ConstraintsSheet and ProfessorRow are definitely defined, as are the UserForm and OptionButton names."* and thinking that the error might be different depending on the call of the thread.

**UPDATE**
After your debug, we have clarified that the error comes from the fact that your rowIndex variable, namely `ProfessorRow`, enters the call `Cells(ProfessorRow,3).Value` with a value of 0, which is forbidden and cause a Object-defined error 1004 since the line 0 does not exist in the spreadsheet.

As long as you don't write how you assign the variable, we cannot help you further. But what's sure is that you have to make sure that the variable `ProfessorRow` takes the correct row value you are looking for. Just for information, if what you do is only what you have reported in your comment, i.e.

```
Dim ProfessorRow As Integer
```

... I inform you that the declaration of the variable will make the variable defaulting to 0, so if you don't assign it lately you will not get rid of the error. Hope a debug session will finally get your problem fixed, the issue lies on here.

Comment: This looks close. When I run a line of code even like
    While Sheets(ConstraintsSheet).Cells(counter, 1).Value <> ""
It's not actually accessing ConstraintsSheet. Is there any way to point it to the workbook it's called from?